# Argumento inválido -Werror al compilar proyecto Kotlin

Tags: maven, kotlin

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Kotlin que usa Maven para el manejo y automatización de los builds. Y uso el comando `mvn verify` para construir y compilar el proyecto y que corran los tests.

Quiero que cuando se compile el proyecto, no sólo falle cuando encuentre un error, sino que también trate los avisos (warnings) como errores y no compile si hay warnings. Busqué en Internet y encontré una posible solución: añadir el argumento `-Werror` a la configuración del artefacto `kotlin-maven-plugin`. Como esto:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <experimentalCoroutines>enable</experimentalCoroutines>
    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
    <args>
      <arg>
        -Werror
      </arg>
    </args>
  </configuration>
  ...
```

Pero cuando hago `mvn verify` obtengo el siguiente error:

> Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.51:compile (compile) on project fridge: Invalid argument: -Werror -> [Help 1]

Curiosamente, si lo que hago es Build > Rebuild Project desde el menú de IntelliJ, no recibo ese error y la compilación falla cuando hay un warning (como quiero). ¿Por qué puede suceder eso y qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Estoy usando:

- Apache Maven 3.5.2 (versión de Java 1.8.0_151)
- Librería de Kotlin 1.1.51
- IntelliJ IDEA Community 2017.2
- Plugin de Kotlin para IntelliJ 1.2.10-release-IJ2017.2-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era la versión de Kotlin que estábamos usando y la del plugin de IntelliJ no eran la misma, y el argumento `-Werror` no se incluyó hasta una versión más moderna de Kotlin. Al hacer `mvn verify` desde línea de comandos se usaba Kotlin 1.1.51 (que no permite `-Werror`); mientras que al hacer Build > Rebuild Project se usaba la 1.2.10 (que sí permite `-Werror`).

La solución fue, después de comprobar que el proyecto no iba a verse impactado con el cambio, actualizar la versión de la biblioteca de Kotlin a una más moderna (la 1.2.21) y ya de paso también actualizar el plugin de Kotlin de IntelliJ para que use la misma versión.

Para actualizar la versión de Kotlin utilizada en el proyecto, se indica en el fichero pom:

```
<kotlin.version>1.2.21</kotlin.version>
```

Y todas las nuevas librerías y dependencias se descargarán y actualizarán automáticamente al compilar el proyecto.